# Can't launch published WPF application

Tags: wpf, publish

I'm trying to test my app outside of visual studio.
I've selected project->publish->path on my desktop->from CD or DVD->not online

I install the project from the setup.exe, but when i launch it, nothing happens. No error message, no windows popping, nothing.
How can i fix that or check what's wrong ?

Comment: Include traces in your code.

Comment: So this is a .net core WPF application?  What kind of project are you using to generate the setup.exe?  Are you using a folder publish profile?

Comment: .Net framework 4.6.1 on visual studio 2017

Comment: Did you try using a path other than the Desktop? I kind of remember such a problem.

Comment: Open visual studio and choose Attach to Process the see what error pops up